# Why does the right click menu show on the other screen in Chrome?

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, google-chrome

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my laptop with an external monitor connected to it. My setup is such that the laptop screen is on the left and the external monitor is on the right.

Now, whenever I right click on the left half of my 2<sup>nd</sup> screen i.e. the external monitor, the menu shows up on the right edge of the 1<sup>st</sup> screen i.e. the laptop screen.

If I right-click on the right half of the 2<sup>nd</sup> screen then the menu shows up correctly. Refer [screenshot 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OH2uL.png).

I am using Google Chrome (Version 46.0.2490.71). Right-click works fine in Firefox and other applications.

**Screenshot 1:**

[image: Screenshot 1]

Screenshot 2: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3gfV.png)

Screenshot 3: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEq4M.png)

Screenshot 4: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OH2uL.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a [bug in Chrome/Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=378945), which is said to be fixed as of Chrome version 47.0.2500.

Comment: Had to use `google-chrome-beta` to get version 47. But that did fix the issue. Thanks! :)

Comment: This issue still persists for me in 49.0.2623.108 Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)

Comment: I too have this problem with Ubuntu 16.04 on Chromium Version 50.0.2661.102 Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit). Even the normal Chrome menu is positioned wrong.  The Google-Chrome app (proprietary) does not have this problem on the same screens.