# Right click menu shown with offset only for chrome (ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, google-chrome, ubuntu-mate, xinerama

I have 6 screens with 2 GTX 1070 TI and nvidia xinerama settings enabled (ubuntu 18.04 Mate). I can use  all applications correctly except chrome : when I do a right click, the menu is shown with an offset equivalent to 2 screens (3840px) to the left. Idem for select options and any contextual menu (title on html element, even the 3 dot option in the top right corner for chrome options). I saw [some posts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/687743/why-does-the-right-click-menu-show-on-the-other-screen-in-chrome) about this problem in earlier chrome versions but I failed to make it work here.

I don't find anything related in recent chrome version (*mine is Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)*)

[Demo with right click](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12vLuCyMVktz8jJQViwSqF8SfYQQJFnJJ/view?usp=sharing) : See the mouse on the right and the menu on the far left

I doubt there is a problem in my X config because it seems to be chrome related. I don't have any problem with firefox or any other app (tested explorer, phpstorm, desktop right click ...)

I asked for help with feedback option on chrome and waiting for help there too, but maybe someone has already seen this problem with recent chrome versions ?

Thanks for any hint

Answer (score 0):

I tried with a live cd on ubuntu and everything worked as expected (without any configuration needed other than positioning the 6 screens correctly). So i choose to format my partition as I did not need anything.

Everything works now, maybe my previous configuration was corrupted somewhere.

It's on ubuntu 18.04 with default Gnome desktop, 6 screens and correct window placement.

Comment: xan you please share your xorg config? I am having the same problem.

Comment: I submitted a bug report for Chromium [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1137258) describing the same problem occurring with an old Xorg version and Xinerama enabled.